# Yosemite Kernel will not compile

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

I seem to have a problem with Yosemite compiling.

I Have downloaded

dtrace-118.1
AvailabilityVersions-9
xnu-2782.1.97

It seems like the command line tools are not installed but a previous kernel version works, I replaced the makedefs folder from the previous kernel and well it starts compiling but of course fails.

The  error I have is here:
[removed]

Comment: Please give us more infos, and do not host text files on third party websites, copy the relevant content here.

Comment: Unfortunately the error log exceeds the character limit here plus loses formating here, it also exceeds on pastebin. But if it is against the rules I shall remove it now. I have Xcode 6.1 & cmd line tools installed. @GuillaumeAlgis

Comment: Fixed, problem in the xnu-2782.1.97/makedefs -> MakeInc.cmd

Line 37

SDKROOT ?= macosx.internal

Replace

SDKROOT ?= /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. It's because the new kernel uses the macosx.internal SDK to compile by default which obviously isn't available because it's Apples internal SDK. If you use the standard macosx SDK it'll compile fine. I used:

make TARGET_CONFIGS="RELEASE X86_64 NONE" SDKROOT=macosx

And I'm currently running the kernel without any issues on my late 2009 MacBook. If you have a Haswell CPU then change the arch type to "X86_64H".

Also while I'm on the topic I noticed there's a couple of new platforms listed under SUPPORTED_PLATFORMS in makedefs/MakeInc.def. iPhoneOSNano and iPhoneNanoSimulator. I'm guessing they're for the Apple Watch. None of the actual code is available but it's mentioned in some makefiles.

Comment: Yeah I did see a bit of that when I was comparing files but didn't go too much into it as was just trying to get the kernel compiled to work on some hacks. Thank you for the alt Answer as it is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, problem in the xnu-2782.1.97/makedefs -> MakeInc.cmd Line 37 SDKROOT ?= macosx.internal Replace SDKROOT ?= / –